# Finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, finite-fields, alternative-proof

Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra contains a proof that a finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field, $F$, is cyclic. However the seems unnecessarily complex to me. Certainly their version works (pictured below), but I'm curious why they don't simply take the approach of adding $(1,...,1)\in(\mathbb{Z}/n_1\mathbb{Z}\times\cdots\mathbb{Z}/n_k\mathbb{Z})$ to itself $n_1\cdot n_2\cdots n_k$ times to show that the group necessarily has a generator. Does that approach somehow fail?

Dummit & Foote's proof:

[image: Proof from Dummit & Foote]

Comment: How would that show that the group has a generator?

Comment: If $k>1$, then that group isn't cyclic, so one has to prove $k=1$.

Comment: Why is the group not cyclic if k>1?

Comment: Keep in mind that, in an additive group, if $nx=0$, that does not show that $x$ has order $n$, only that it has order dividing $n$.

Comment: @JFox It might help you to consider an explicit example. Take $Z/2Z \times Z/2Z$, and see what elements you get if you add $(1,1)$ repeatedly to itself.

Comment: Ah I see, I think I was imagining $n_1,...,n_k$ as coprime but yeah that doesn't make sense. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, in fact, it's the complete opposite, in this situation, we have $n_k\mid\cdots\mid n_1$.